# React Navigation blank screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently updated my Expo app to React Navigation 1.0.0-beta.19. Since then, it has been showing me only white screen. What can be the issue?

Here is the snack for reproduction.
https://snack.expo.io/@rajat1saxena/react-navigation-test

Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can fix this by removing the line: `alignItems: 'center'`

Your container styles should look like this:

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
}
```

The view is using a undetermined width, when you use `alignItems: 'center'` it will push your content to the center. Because there is no set width the width will be 0!

By removing or changing `alignItems` you allow flex to fill the view.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issues by removing the SafeAreaView enclosing the ReactNavigator.

Code with issue:

```
<SafeAreaView>
 <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Code without issue:

```
 <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Evan Bacon!

By removing `alignItems: 'center'` my issue is resolved.

Just compare below 2 `App.js` files..

`App.js with issue`

```
<View style={styles.container}>
<StatusBar style="auto" />
<SafeAreaProvider>
    <NavigationContainer theme={DefaultTheme}>
        <StackNavigator /> // My Stack Navigator Component
    </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({container: {flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }});
```

`working App.js`

```
<View style={styles.container}>
<StatusBar style="auto" />
<SafeAreaProvider>
    <NavigationContainer theme={DefaultTheme}>
        <StackNavigator /> // My Stack Navigator Component
    </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({container: {flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }});
```

The main difference is in the styles of container. If we add `alignItem: 'center'` in your app.js `return <View></View>` you will face the same issue.

Just remove `alignItem: 'center'` from parent `<View></View>` and it will work.